# Dagger 2 with Instant App

Tags: dagger-2, android-instant-apps, dagger

I've been working on instant app for a few days. I didn't get it compiled yet due to Dagger issue.

The project is split into `base`, `export`, `preview` as features.

In `export` module

```
@ExportScope
@Component(
        modules = [DrawExportModule::class],
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class])
interface DrawExportComponent: AndroidInjector<LiveDrawingExportActivity> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<LiveDrawingExportActivity>(){
        abstract fun plus(component: AppComponent): Builder
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ActivityBindingModule::class,
    ServiceBindingModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(context: Context): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: LiveMessageApplication)
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
   @Module(includes = [(DataModule::class)])
   class AppModule {
   @Singleton
   @Provides
   fun provideStateManager(): StateManager {
        return StateManager.getInstance()
   }
}
```

Compile error log

```
    /Users/*/features/export/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/*/ui/draw/di/DrawExportComponent.java:8: 
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] *.ui.StateManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract interface DrawExportComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.ctech.livemessage.ui.draw.LiveDrawingExportActivity> {
                    ^
          *.ui.StateManager is injected at
              *.LiveDrawingExportActivity.stateManager
          *.LiveDrawingExportActivity is injected at
              dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
```

It seems to me dependency component doesn't work in this case. I have no clue to go forward.

More information
base/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion deps.build.compileSdkVersion

    baseFeature = true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion deps.build.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion deps.build.targetSdkVersion

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {

    application project(":installed")
    feature project(":features:export")
    feature project(":features:preview")
}
```

export/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion deps.build.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion deps.build.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion deps.build.targetSdkVersion
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../../proguard.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'libs'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation project(':features:base')

    kapt deps.dagger.compiler
    kapt deps.dagger.androidCompiler

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `DrawExportComponent` doesn't see `StateManager`, because the latter is part of `AppComponent`.

Unlike subcomponents, with component dependencies, dependent components don't get access to all of parent component. You have to explicitly specify what's shared, by adding:

```
fun stateManager(): StateManager
```

to your `AppComponent`.

More info in [official documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.14/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful.